Simple animation using a JLabel and ImageIcon throwing an exception
I'm making a simple static animation at the start of my program, and it uses a timer and ImageIcons to work. Here is the code:
int staticChecker = 0;
    private void btnStartMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        pnlStart.setVisible(false);
        pnlMenu.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer t;
        t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 12; i <= 19; i++) {
                    lblStatic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource((12+staticChecker) + ".png")));
                    staticChecker++;
                    if (staticChecker >= 19) {
                        i = 12;
                        staticChecker = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

            t.start();
            
    }                                     

I'm not sure what the problem might be. It just keeps throwing a NullPointerException. Please help!

You need the correct url. Guessing:  lblStatic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(("/" + (12+staticChecker) + ".png"))); You'd be better off just changing the image btw. Nicer icon.setImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(("/%d.png".formatted(12+staticChecker)))); (brackets could be wrong)

Did you look at the exception’s stack trace?  Its entire purpose is to tell you exactly where the problem lies.
